# Python how to implement code to GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

Im very new to making GUI in python and I have searched everywhere but cant find what im looking for. I simply want to have a program where the user inputs a radius and the program prints out the area of that radius in a label with the help of either a button click or enter. Thanks in advance :)

```
import Tkinter, math

class calc_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
def __init__(self,parent):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
    self.grid()

    self.entryVariable = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
    self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
    self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
    self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
    self.entryVariable.set(u"Radius")

    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click to convert",command=self.OnButtonClick)
    button.grid(column=1,row=0)

    self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,anchor="w",fg="white",bg="gray")
    label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
    self.labelVariable.set(u"Please enter a radius.")

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.resizable(True,False)
    self.update()
    self.geometry(self.geometry())       
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def OnButtonClick(self):
    self.labelVariable.set( self.convertVariable.get() )
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def OnPressEnter(self,event):
    self.converter()
    self.labelVariable.set( self.convertVariable.get() )
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def converter(self):
    self.convertVariable(math.pi * self.entryVariable.get()**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = calc_tk(None)
app.title('Radius Converter')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: everything but the "def converter" is "copied" from somewhere else because im still learning, but I cant figure out how to properly add the math into the code, so everything in "def converter" is me trying to figure it out

Comment: You have a couple problems.  You should call `self.converter()` as the first line in `OnPressEnter()`.  You cannot add strings to floats.  You should do something more like `"{} is the area.".format(self.convertVariable.get())`.  `converter()` defines `convertVariable`, but sets `convert`.  Switch the `self.convert` to `self.convertVariable`.  The `self.entryVariable` is a `StringVar`, so remember to convert it before trying to do math with it.  That would be `float(...)`, or just use a `DoubleVar`.  I don't think I forgot anything, but tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of Tkinter with python, I suggest Kivy with Python, so much easier!

Comment: I've made some changes now, but I didn't understand all of it, I'll edit the script above. Thanks a lot for the help btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code little bit. Now code will display area on the label as you mentioned.Check the code.If I am wrong  let me know.

```html
import Tkinter, math

class calc_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Radius")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click to convert",command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,anchor="w",fg="white",bg="gray")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Please enter a radius.")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick(self):
       
        self.labelVariable.set( str(self.converter())+" is the area." )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( str(self.converter())+" is the area." )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def converter(self):
        print self.entryVariable.get()
        return (math.pi * (float(self.entryVariable.get()) * float(self.entryVariable.get())))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = calc_tk(None)
    app.title('Radius Converter')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So I applied the modifications but now I get a syntax error and it blames the ":" in  `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: its indentation issue.. i have modified it.

Comment: That code shows as code snippet. Have you tested that it is possible to run it?